# Java Swagger Webservice dont run in Tomcat Server but in Maven TomEE?

Tags: java, maven, web-services, tomcat, swagger

i have a little problem.
i have create a little Webserive to test Swagger ...
The webservice get back only an integer ... (Testwebservice)
when i start in the Projektfolder

```
mvn run:tomee
```

There works fine i can test it with postman and i become my integer value

but when i try to deploy the WAR File in a classic Tomcat Server --> Nothing ... Postman get back a 404 Error the logfiles a emty

i have merged the server.xml and web.xml in the /conf directory between Tomcat and TomEE but i cant find a different

the tomcat is installed by APT-GET on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

tomcat is running, i can open the Sample Page from Tomcat and i can use the Tomcat manager to deploy my WAR File

i need help !

thanks

EDIT:
/var/lib/tomcat8/log/catalina.out:

```
Nov 27, 2017 9:25:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext 
reload
INFORMATION: Reloading Context with name [/swagger-cxf-server-1.0.0] 
has started
Nov 27, 2017 9:25:16 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no 
TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs 
that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded 
JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation 
time.
Nov 27, 2017 9:25:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext 
reload
INFORMATION: Reloading Context with name [/swagger-cxf-server-1.0.0] 
is completed
Nov 27, 2017 9:28:20 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no 
TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs 
that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded 
JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation 
time.
Nov 27, 2017 9:36:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFORMATION: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 27, 2017 9:36:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService 
stopInternal
INFORMATION: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 27, 2017 9:36:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFORMATION: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 27, 2017 9:36:27 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFORMATION: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

the complete log file can you see here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/26057420/

here is the pom.xml:

pom.xml: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26057900

Comment: Tomcat Version is 8
Tomee version is 1.71

Comment: The Tomcat logs will tell you more about the issue. Add them to your question wo we can provide help.

Comment: @PierreB. i have add the logs to the Post now, you need other logs as catalina.out ?

Comment: What do have have  in your pom? Can you show?

Comment: @pirho yes shure

Comment: pom.xml: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26057900/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the reason is because `Tomcat` < `TomEE`. So just installing `tomcat8` might not be enough. Guess it is about some `jax-rs` stuff that is expected to be found in container side.

From [tomee page](https://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)

> Apache TomEE, pronounced "Tommy", is an all-Apache Java EE 6 Web
>   Profile certified stack where Apache Tomcat is top dog.

You have two options (both can be found from this [download page](https://tomee.apache.org/download-ng.html) of TomEE site. 
)

1. drop *TomEE Plus Webapp* war to current tomcat installation (easiest, for trying if works)
2. replace current tomcat installation with *TomEE plus* stand-alone (includes most suitable version of tomcatX, **recommended option**)